# Simplify Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been struggling to simplify some query selectors. The best I could do is this.

```
$($(".NextYearDays td[data-index='1'], .NextYearDays td[data-index='2'] , .NextYearDays td[data-index='3']")).on("change", function ()
{

});
```

Is there a way to include the list of indexes I want without expanding the selector with same base structure?

Comment: You can use something like `$('.NextYearDays td').filter(function () { return +$(this).data('index') < 4 })` (but it really depends on the HTML and the elements you *don't* want to select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) @Comelius Scheepers! We hope you like it here.

You can use the `.filter()` method as suggested by @Chris G, and use something like `[list-of-indices].includes( ... )`:

```
$('.NextYearDays td[data-index]').filter(function() {
    return [1,2,3].includes(+$(this).data('index'))
}).on('change', function() {
    //event code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Without JQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) you could use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and check the index value within the event handler.

Side note: `change` is not a valid event for `<td>`.

```js
const handle = evt => {
  const indx = evt.target.dataset.index;
  if (indx && [2,3,5].find( v => v === +indx )) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`hi from ${evt.target.dataset.index}`);
  }
};
document.addEventListener("click", handle);
```

```css
td {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-index="1"> 1 </td>
    <td data-index="2"> 2 </td>
    <td data-index="3"> 3 </td>
    <td data-index="4"> 4 </td>
    <td data-index="5"> 5 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```